# PHP / ASCII serious mind boggling situation with non-printable characters

Tags: php, html, tags, hex, ascii

Can someone tell me why those two tags are doing different things? 
(first string doesnt work when upload it to server, second is fine)

```
<a href="﻿http://www.example.com">a</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">a</a>
```

I ran conversion to HEX values and it seems there is at least one character more in first string:

```
3c6120687265663d223f687474703a2f2f7777772e6578616d706c652e636f6d223e613c2f613e0d0a
3c6120687265663d22  687474703a2f2f7777772e6578616d706c652e636f6d223e613c2f613e
```

Second string is handwritten, first is generated by PHP function:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("./data/test.txt", "r");
$homepage = trim(fgets($handle, 4096));
?>

<a href="<?php echo $homepage;?>">a</a>
```

in test.txt, there is:

```
http://www.example.com
```

on the first line, then few more lines of text.

Moreover, the code for invisible character seems to be 3f, which is question mark, that should be visible, right?

Comment: also note the first string is ending in: `\n\r`

Comment: @ka ᵠ: nope, it's just `\n` there https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4486681/bom.png

Comment: @zerkms: hmm... in his paste there's `0D0A` (`\n\r` ! strange as it's used as `\r\n` on windows) and in your bom.png there's only a `0A` (ascii 10 `\r`)

Comment: @ka ᵠ: `0x0A` is a New Line character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the file: `EF BB BF`.

The *correct* solution is to fix the algorithm that puts the data to the file (to not put BOM), or if the file is static - just remove it once with any advanced enough text editor (like Notepad++ or so), but as a quick and dirty solution you can just remove it in runtime:

```
if (substr($homepage, 0, 3) == pack('CCC', 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)) {
    $homepage = substr($homepage, 3);
}
```

Comment: Where in the question do you see that? Or are you just saying that there *might* be a BOM?

Comment: @IMSoP: I copied the strings and found it out there. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4486681/bom.png

Comment: I saw it in notepad++ with show all character option, but there was nothing in the middle of string. Can you also explain me why is there hex code 3f which is question mark? Or did I use wrong HEX convertor?

Comment: @user1590642: see the screenshot from the comment above as well. For notepad++ you need to install hex editor plugin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/) to see that

Comment: @IMSoP: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. The issue with 2 strings in the question is that there is a BOM in the middle of the first one.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much...can you also explain me, how did the BOM got there? I created it in windows notepad, is it usual that it puts this symbol at the start?

Comment: @zerkms Yep, sorry, misunderstood.

Comment: @user1590642: 1. here is a correct dump with BOM visible http://ideone.com/4eDBwO 2. It's in the original file `test.txt` and your editor put it there. Just created a new file in `notepad.exe`, it's fine, no BOM. So I'm assuming it was another editor.

Comment: @zerkms Notepad won't save in UTF-8 at all by default; however, if you tell it to do so, it will include a BOM, because that is it's primary way of detecting encoding when you next open the file.

Comment: Strange thing is, that Notepad++ does not see BOM but when I create new document in it, it creates it without BOM. I am new to PHP, but got few years of experience in C++, I doesnt remember having any problems with BOM when loading files C++. Interesting :)

Comment: ahh, IMSoP is right, I use UTF-8 encoding because my native language uses symbols like ščřž :) Thats also the reason why I never enountered it before, only using UTF-8when doing PHP and websites.

Comment: @user1590642 Aha. Then the answer is to use a more fully-featured text editor. Notepad's Unicode functionality, like everything else about it, is fairly rudimentary and inflexible.

Comment: @IMSoP: yeah, I expected that and for testing added non-ascii-safe characters (Cyrillic, I'm Russian) assuming it will be UTF-8, though it was smarter and saved it in `cp1251` :-S

Comment: @zerkms How embarassing, to be out-smarted by notepad.exe ;)